# Is Java RMI a good alternative to Axis2 SOAP?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-axis, rmi, xml-rpc

If server and client are Java only, would RMI be more efficient (bandwidth and latency) compared to SOAP implemented by Axis2? I know RMI has lost popularity on late years, but that doesn't mean it can't be used.

And how about XML-RPC?

Comment: RMI is based on Java Serialization so it should be quite efficient.

Comment: What about REST? [Web services are dead -- long live REST](http://www.infoworld.com/d/application-development/web-services-are-dead-long-live-rest-211395)

Comment: RMI will be faster but it lacks certain features like Server-level security - however this can be overlooked if two internal enterprise systems are used. The other issue can be Loan Balancing Feature. Webservices has its own overhead like Marshalling / Unmarshalling but given that now a days server more powerful , that shouldnt be any issue. In foresight , webservices makes your Enterprises more SOA oriented. Thus it would help in better design if you need to extend your service to other parties

Comment: @user1428716 You mean 'load balancing feature', and RMI doesn't have one, although RMI/IIOP can when using a suitable ORB.

Comment: Very good point about security. I read about REST and didn't see it so good, any idea about its performance? I'll read the link soon, but if I can use JSON and deal with Stateless situation, and it's really faster then Axis2, that may be promising.

Comment: Could anyone share experience on XML-RPC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RMI has some interesting features and is reasonably fast, but also has some problems:

1. You have to make sure everything you're serializing implements Serializable.
2. You have to make sure the server and client have exactly the same version of all the Serializable classes, and are deployed at exactly the same time, and that every class that you serialize (including fields held by the serializable objects) uses serialVersionUID appropriately.  Otherwise you will be in a world of pain (read: "serial version mismatch").
3. You have to ensure that the classes that you serialize are not holding onto references to objects that eventually hold references to large objects, or else you will be very surprised about the size of the packets going over the wire.
4. If you ever decide to access the service from anything but Java, you will have to write another remote access layer.
5. There is no #5.

In practice, I would almost always recommend a REST service these days.  It's so easy to create small Java objects and use Gson or Jackson or something to marshal the data back and forth that the advantages of RMI are vanishingly small in comparison.

Comment: (2) is not correct. See the [Versioning of Serialized Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html) chapter in the Object Serialization Specification. If (2) was correct the chapter wouldn't exist.

Comment: Very good answer, tnx! If (2) is really untrue, and of course I can keep everything inside Java, then (3) isn't an issue at all. For building a WebService we have to manage passing data after all, and the same issue may happen with any other solution that automatically takes objects and throw them without needing explicit conversion code.

Comment: I'll read the above code and think about REST and JSON, maybe this can be the middle solution between RMI and SOAP.

Comment: @EJP, I know that (2) is technically not always true.  However, it is effectively true so often (due to third-party libraries, poorly written code, accidental references, etc.) that it might as well be.  A previous client of mine was using EJBs with DTOs with serialVersionUIDs set.  Well, it turns out one wasn't set, and one of our developers reordered a couple of fields (should be harmless, right?).  Our test environment was down for a whole day due to the dozens of dependent projects all failing with serial version mismatches and having to be rebuilt and redeployed.  Not a good situation.

Comment: @EricGalluzzo One of the problems with RMI and Serialization is the massive amount of misinformation that has been perpetrated about both. Don't be part of that problem. Either (2) is true or it isn't true, and it isn't. Your client should have read that chapter; he should have defined a `serialVersionUID` for every `Serializable` class in accordance with what every IDE on the planet tells you to; and he shouldn't have ever changed them. It's possible to break anything, but that's not a reason to pretend that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, instead of leaving your server down for so long, you could also have reverted to a tested revision/baseline, and once back working you could compare it with your latest code. Would be better to find what caused the incident and at the same time you could do it with your server back working.

Comment: Well I've decided to use RESTlet and Jackson, they are faster (I still must benchmark myself) then Axis2 and do the job if WebService isn't too behavior-oriented (a big variety of operations over the same resource). Thanks a lot for the comments!